# Unable to download a copy of a document

Tags: ecb-menu, download

I have a document type that I am unable to use the ECB menu item 'download a copy'. I get a runtime error when trying to download. Looking at the URL it is unable to get the url for the file I want to delete. This works for other content types. The URL it is trying to send me to when it gets the error is:

```
https://site/_layouts/15/download.aspx?SourceUrl=undefined&FldUrl=&Source=https%3A%2F%2Fsite%2FPages%2FMyDocuments%2Easpx
```

The source url is undefined where it is a legitimate value for other content types.

I then decided to make my own button and hide the default one for this content type. However it is still unable to find the URL for any documents of this type. Instead it gets:

```
https://site/_layouts/15/download.aspx?SourceUrl={ItemUrl}&FldUrl=&Source=https%3A%2F%2Fsite/Pages/MyDocuments.aspx
```

I tried using CAML Designer and am able to retrieve the FileRef for all documents in the library. And any user with full control can download a document but giving every user full control isn't an option. Does anyone know why this is happening or a workaround for this?

This uses a custom view of the documents library. So there is the AllItems.aspx page as well as a seperate page that less privileged users get redirected to. Users can download from the AllItems page but not the documents unless they have full control.

Comment: I've seen similar problems, related to corruption in the Content Database. You should check the integrity of your SQL Database: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms139858.aspx

Comment: I'll look into it, the same error can be replicated on others environments though so it possibly isn't related to the content database?

Comment: Ok, what is the file type of the file? Since it seems the problem is actually with a file type rather than something else.

Comment: It's an xlsx but it isn't the file type, I can spreadsheets as another content type and download a copy. I thought it might be a permissions problem but granted another group all permissions and still can't download a copy.

Comment: You said users with full control aren't having any issues. What permission level does the account you're testing with have?

Comment: It's a custom permission level, for list items they have all permissions but Manage Lists, Override List Behaviors, Approve Items and Delete Versions.